# How to select elements using many classes

Tags: python, selenium

How do i select this class ?

`button.btn.swx-audio-call-btn.primary.circle`

I tried `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="swx-audio-call-btn"]').click()`, no result

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.button.btn.swx-audio-call-btn.primary.circle')
```